# Hypersurfaces covered by high genus curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. The first question is the following:

1. Is there a standard name or notation for the notion: the smallest integer (denoted by $g_{cov}(X)$ for now) such that through any point $x\in X$, there is a genus $g$ curve with $g\leq g_{cov}(X)$?

Then suppose $X_d$ is a general (or very general if needed) degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$.

2. Do we know what is $g_{cov}(X_d)$ in terms of $d$ and $n$? If it's not easy to write down, do we know for example whether it is a polynomial in $d$ for every $n$ (or something like that)?

Certainly if $n=2$ we have degree-genus formula. For $n=3$, we have the Noether-Lefschetz theorem. And by cutting down using hyperplanes, $n=2$ case gives an upper bound for all $n$.

---

Edit: Indeed, there are some subtleties about the definition that I didn't realize. I think I want to allow for singular curves as well. And genus means geometric genus.

Comment: Frank Gounelas has studied a related notion of a variety being connected via genus-g curves, in this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.4055v2.pdf. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: You should clarify whether you require your covering curves to be smooth.

Comment: There are articles of Clemens, Ein, Pacienza, Voisin, and Geng Xu on lower bounds of genera of subvarieties of hypersurfaces.  There are also recent results of Riedl-Yang in this direction trying to "limit" rational curves contained in the hypersurface.  These results are not (usually) about subvarieties that "sweep out" the hypersurface; they are about proving that a very general hypersurface contains *no* subvariety of small genus.

Comment: @abx Thanks for pointing it out. I think I want singular curves as well. But I'd love to see any example where requiring smooth makes a different answer.

Comment: A quartic surface $X_4$ might already be an example.  (Very) generally, all smooth curves on $X_4$ are sections of $d\cdot H$ and so have genus at least $3$, but the tangent plane at any point intersects $X_4$ in a quartic that is singular at that point and thus has genus at most $2$.  In fact, counting dimensions suggests that every point lies on a finite but positive number of plane sections that have at least two singularities, and thus genus at most $1$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the references. I tried to look up some of them. In the meantime, has anybody used this kind of notion to measure the irrationality of a variety? I know there is a recent work by Ein, Lazarsfeld and Ullery measuring irrationality by for example the gonality of covering curves. As one of the motivations of the question, I was wondering whether there will be troubles if one uses geometric or arithmetic genus instead of gonality.

Comment: There are a couple of excellent textbooks about curves on varieties.  One is written by J'anos Koll'ar, and the other is written by Olivier Debarre.  I recommend that you look at those books.